# How to run nodejs script that uses Puppeteer on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I have created a NodeJs script that uses Puppeteer to grab some data from a website and put it on a json file.

Here is my *Dyno*:

[image]

If I enter the heroku bash (`heroku run bash -a my-app`) and I run the script (`npm run start`) it works like a charm.

Instead, if I launch the script clicking on "Open app" button I get a page with the following error:

[image]

Having a look at logs I see this:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=653dbf69-d35c-4017-bxxf-cc0e1a5xxxce fwd="37.159.47.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-01T07:24:50.316302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b49ac035-axxx-4372-a59e-118bcxxx6a3b fwd="37.159.47.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have spent a lot of time searching for H10 error and I have tried every solution I encountered, none worked.

The point is: what is the right way to launch a NodeJs script since I'm using Puppeteer and then I have no web page to show?
If I use the bash when I close it the script is killed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out how to run a script that is not a web app.
I have changed "web" to "worker" in the Procfile:

`worker: npm start`

and then turn off the **web** dynos and turn on the fresh new **worker**:

[image]

(You can reach the same with Heroku CLI: `heroku scale web=0 worker=1`)

[Source of solution](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-classic/issues/3994#issuecomment-441136287).

Answer (score 0):

Do you installed the puppeter webpack that recomends heroku? other solution that worked for me is to use "chrome-aws-lambda" library that integrates puppeteer and work in hostings like vercel or heroku

example of the library

```
import chromium from "chrome-aws-lambda";
const browser = chromium.puppeteer."any puppeteer function"
```

i hope this help you.